# Spring HttpServletRequest unaccessible in HystrixCommand

Tags: spring, hystrix

Inside a Javanica annotated `@HystrixCommand` we are checking if the request was in an actual HTTP servlet request by checking:

```
RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes() != null;
```

However invoked from a `@HystrixCommand` this condition is always false, even if the request came from a Spring MVC request.

If I remove the `@HystrixCommand` annotation everything works fine.
We also tried to use the `HttpServletRequest` directly, this works fine (without `@HystrixCommand`):

```
LOGGER.info(request.getHeader("X-Client"));
```

With annotated `@HystrixCommand` we are facing exception indicating I am not in an valid `HttpServletRequest`. I know it is due to Hystrix running commands in separate Threads from its own ThreadPool and tried to do this, but doesn't work either:

```
public class RequestServletFilter implements Filter {

@Override
public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
    // No Impl
}

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {
    HystrixRequestContext context = HystrixRequestContext.initializeContext();
    try {
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    } finally {
        context.shutdown();
    }
}

@Override
public void destroy() {
    // No Impl
}
```

Does someone have a clue how to delegate the Spring `HttpServletRequest` into HystrixCommands?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hmm... Isn't actually a bit smelly you are accessing the request at all? Feels like you ar trying to do something you shouldn't be doing in the first place.

Comment: Our application serves different countries (clients), therefore when it comes to building REST urls to retreive data from 3rd party backends the Client has to be considered in the URL. Therefore, we delegated this Client handling out into a custom ClientContext.java which we can autowired whereever needed. This is just for comfortability, otherwise we would need to loop through the client everywhere which is a pain.

Comment: But then what has that to do with injecting a `HttpServletRequest` into a `@HystrixCommand` annotated method? Also nice to know are you using plain Hystrix or the Spring Cloud wrapped one? I would say that your `ClientContext` should be decoupled from the request (you might want to create it based on an incoming request but after that should not rely on it anymore). Which would make sharing the object (which I hope is readonly) easier.

Comment: We are using plain hystrix + javanica 1.5.9. We do not autowire the HttpServletRequest directly in the @HystrixCommand annotated Repository, but the ClientContext. And the ClientContext makes use of the HttpServletRequest by offering a method getRequestSpecificClient(); 

This method returns null, if there is no HttpServletRequest available. In this case there is, but it remains returning null because of the separated HystrixCommand Thread.
Workaround would be to check for the current client in the Service only and then route the client through everywhere. But as I said this is unconvinient

Comment: That is why I suggested that the `ClientContext` should work regardless of the current request or not. That probably relies on the `RequestContextHolder` which is a `ThreadLocal`. IMHO you should populate the `ClientContext` with the needed properties to do its work. If you are using that to access the current request everywhere in your code base I would say that is a smell.

Comment: If you are using a `DispatcherServlet` you could set the `threadContextInheritable` property to `true` which would allow for sharing the `RequestContext` between threads... Although I would consider that a hack/patch and not a real solution.

Comment: I know it sounds messy, but believe me its pretty neat not to have to deal with client differentiation and other context attributes, such as viewport, language etc. I have a look for your hint

Comment: I'm not saying it isn't neat, I'm saying that you should profile the `ClientContext` with it and not rely on other apps retrieving that through the hacked in request. This basically also makes your whole application dependent on the web layer each and every class...

Comment: Okay if I got your intention correctly you want me to populate the ClientContext myself and make it decoupled of the Spring HttpServletRequest. However this won't change anything since the ClientContext itself would become Context sensitive using some ThreadLocal construct, etc. instead of the underlying HttpServletRequest. BTW your hint with RequestContextHolder.setRequestAttributes(requestAttributes, true); works fine, thanks a lot from Hamburg!!

Comment: You may want to add this solution as an "answer" so that other people can benefit of it as well (independent from the architectural design debate)?

Comment: Ofcourse but sharing that simple object, instead of trying to share your whole request executing context is a whole different thing.

Comment: I will consider that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using the `RequestContextHolder` by default it parameters are not shared (for good reasons!).

Assuming that you are using a `DispatcherServlet` to handle your request you can set its [`threadContextInheritable`] to `true` to have the `RequestContext` and `LocaleContext` shared between requests.

The same applies for the `RequestContextFilter`, it isn't possible with the `RequestContextListener`.

**Note:** I would consider sharing the `HttpServletRequest` between threads as something you shouldn't be doing and should be done with great care!

Comment: I assume sharing the HttpServletRequest to the HystrixCommand is going to get messy when you start to make use of RequestCollapsing in Hystrix right.